# unpacking a struct

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

I have a list of arithmetic expressions that I encode and pack into a struct, as follows:

```
expressions = ["1+12", "16-5", "1-3+4", "12-5", "16+4"]  # 5 expressions; but could be any number
s = struct.pack('h', len(expressions))  # Prepend the number of expressions to the struct
for e in expressions:
    s += struct.pack(f'h{len(e)}s', len(e), e.encode('utf-8'))
```

Later, I want to undo this process, and unpack them two bytes a time. But I can't seem to get this right. Here's my unpacking and decoding code:

```
d = []
for n in range(0, len(expressions), 2):  # Iterate over the struct
    s = struct.unpack('h', expressions[n])
    s = s.decode('utf-8')
    d.append(s)
```

Python is giving me the following error at the unpack call:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

I don't understand the reason for the error. I thought that I'd already encoded the elements into Unicode, so they should be bytes-like. My goal is to build up the original list of expressions again. How can I do this?

Comment: use `pickle`, not `struct`

Comment: `expressions[0]` is equal to `'1 + 12'`, hence the error for `struct.unpack('h', expressions[n])` (n = 0 when the error first occurs). The second argument to `unpack` should be an integer representing the number of bytes in the buffer.

Comment: @Alexander I'm sorry, I've re-read your comment 3 times, but I still don't quite understand what you mean by "number of bytes in the buffer." What buffer? Here's the ```struct s``` I'm trying to unpack: ```b'\x05\x00\x04\x001+12\x04\x0016-5\x05\x001-3+4\x04\x0012-5\x04\x0016+4'```.

Are you saying I should get the length of each element and use that to unpack?

Comment: `Signature: struct.unpack(format, buffer, /)
Docstring:
Return a tuple containing values unpacked according to the format string.

The buffer's size in bytes must be calcsize(format).
` Running your code above resulted in `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. Debugging it and examining the issue, it is because of the `expressions[0]` argument is a string.  This is slightly different, however, from the error you posted.

Comment: Right, it it was a string, I'd use the ```s``` key, not ```h``` to unpack. But I don't know what the ```TypeError``` is about, or how to fix it.

Comment: I am not familiar with your byte formatting.  What does `\x001+12` mean?

Comment: I believe it's just the "1+12" argument in byte form.

Comment: @WaterGuy: ***"what the TypeError is about"**: Read about [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray)